# How do I output the Realm fileURL in a Swift XCTestCase?

Tags: swift, configuration, realm

In my Swift test file; I am getting a crash when I attempt to output the fileURL via console.

I want to print out the fileURL of realm on the console log during a test in setup;

I try:

`print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)`

My code as follows;

```
class MyFirstTests: XCTestCase {
     override class func setUp() {
            super.setUp()
            // Called once before all tests are run

            var uniqueConfiguration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
            uniqueConfiguration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
            uniqueConfiguration.inMemoryIdentifier = "tests"
            Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = uniqueConfiguration
        }

        override func setUp() {
            super.setUp()

            let realm = try! Realm()

            print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    ...
    }
}
```

It crashes when it reaches the fileURL part.

How do I output the fileURL without crashing?

I've tried to wrap it in an `if let` statement; however it never outputs the fileURL in console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileUR` is `nil` when using in-memory Realm, please see [docs here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.3.0/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration7fileURLGSqV10Foundation3URL_).